# Edit GitHub Issue with curl

Tags: github-api

Trying to edit an issue on github via curl.exe (Windows Command Line) and I keep getting the following error.  Any suggestions?

**curl command**

```
curl -X POST -u "someuser" https://api.github.com/repos/myrepo/myproject/issues/4 -d '{"labels": "["bug"]"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

**error Message**

```
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue"
}
```

Comment: Your quotes are wrong.

Comment: That is fair, however, I will get the same thing when removing the quotes around `["bug"]`.

Comment: Here is my command `curl -X POST -u "someuser" https://api.github.com/repos/myrepo/myproject/issues/4 -d '{"labels": ["bug"]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"` or did I miss something?

Comment: ah.  I should note in Linux removing the double quotes around the array works and the label is created.  However, in Windows (using the `curl.exe`) and removing the double quotes around the array it still gives me the same error.  @SLaks - any thoughts around that?

Comment: I don't think Windows supports `'` for argument grouping.

Comment: You are correct.  I posted an answer with examples.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original post was about using curl to edit an issue in GitHub.  I was using the Windows Command line to do it.  As it was pointed out the `'` (single quotes) in the Windows Command line was not going to work.  In the Windows command shell you have to use outer double quotes for the 
string and escape any inner double quotes.

The following command will work via a Windows Command Line.

**Windows Command Line**

`curl.exe -X POST -u "someuser" https://api.github.com/repos/myrepo/myproject/issues/4 -d "{\"labels\":[\"bug\"]}" -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

The following command will work via Linux bash.

**Linux Bash**

`curl -X POST -u "someuser" https://api.github.com/repos/myrepo/myproject/issues/4 -d '{"labels": ["bug"]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"`